# Facing issue in connecting snowflake using pyspark

Tags: python, pyspark, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am using Pycharm IDE and trying to connect snowflake using pyspark.
But getting below error.

```
raise Py4JJavaError(
py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o40.load.
: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: scala/$less$colon$less
    at net.snowflake.spark.snowflake.DefaultSource.shortName(DefaultSource.scala:44)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource$.$anonfun$lookupDataSource$2(DataSource.scala:652)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource$.$anonfun$lookupDataSource$2$adapted(DataSource.scala:652)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike.$anonfun$filterImpl$1(TraversableLike.scala:304)
```

My Code:

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession

sfoptions = {
"sfUrl" : URL
"sfUser" : USER
"sfPassword" : PASSWORD
"sfaccount" : ACCOUNT
}

query="SELECT COUNT(*) from table_name"

spark = SparkSession.builder.appName("demo").master("local").\
    config('spark.jars','../jars/spark-snowflake_2.13-2.10.0-spark_3.2.jar,../jars/snowflake-jdbc-3.13.9.jar').getOrCreate()

SNOWFLAKE_SOURCE_NAME="net.snowflake.spark.snowflake"

df=spark.read.format(SNOWFLAKE_SOURCE_NAME).options(**sfoptions).option("query",query).load()

df.show()
```

Can anyone help to resolve this issue

Comment: Running into the same issue. Were you able to get this resolved?

Comment: Not yet, But now getting different error as ": net.snowflake.client.jdbc.SnowflakeSQLException: JDBC driver encountered communication error. Message: Exception encountered for HTTP request:"

Comment: What did you change to get this new error, @kathir? Your new error seems like a network issue then, if it's an accurate error. Also, it would be helpful if you could post your spark and scala versions.

Comment: Yes its related to network issue. Its not able to establish JDBC connection which pyspark uses default

Answer (score 1):

Check the driver version and ensure they are compatible with Scala versions. In this case you are using `spark-snowflake_2.13-2.10.0-spark_3.2.jar`. This jar is compatible with Scala v2.13 and Spark v3.2. Ensure you have those versions installed. Else, use the jar file that is compatible with your Spark and Scala versions.

Answer (score 0):

If your description is correct, then:

```
SNOWFLAKE_SOURCE_NAME="new.snowflake.spark.snowflake"
```

should be:

```
SNOWFLAKE_SOURCE_NAME="net.snowflake.spark.snowflake"
```

Comment: Still the same error